# Second contact us for another email

Tags: magento2, contact-us

I need a second contact us form that is accessed from another url and the email is sent to another email.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do a custom module, there seems to be one in github that looks good to do what you need, if not, at least it will cover a part of your requirements

https://github.com/Alekseon/magento2-custom-forms-builder